# line chart in r with different dataframe format

Tags: r

For each department I want to see how much they spend in last three weeks in the form of a line chart in r using ggplot.
x -axis would be week and y axis is Amount

```
df <- data.frame(department = c(111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333),
             week = c("w1","w2","w3","w1","w2","w3","w1","w2","w3"),
             Amount =c(34,46,34,40,45,56,67,69,75))

 department  week Amount
    111       w1     34
    111       w2     46
    111       w3     34
    222       w1     40
    222       w2     45
    222       w3     56
    333       w1     67
    333       w2     69
    333       w3     75
```

I am not able to transpose the data setting each unique department values to a column name  and their corresponding Amount in rows. Then it can be done using ggplot I guess.

But Is their any way to do the plot with data in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this suit your needs?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(department = c(111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333),
                 week = c("w1","w2","w3","w1","w2","w3","w1","w2","w3"),
                 Amount =c(34,46,34,40,45,56,67,69,75))

df %>% 
  mutate(department = as.factor(department)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = week, y = Amount, group = department, col = department)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Week", y = "Amount spent", col = "Department")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>